# Помощь с php API

Tags: php, json, api

Мне нужно помощь с API помогите если вам не сложно.

Есть API https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=gastracker&action=gasoracle&apikey=YourApiKeyToken

Мне нужно получить "LastBlock" как это сделать с помощью curl и json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрать данные из данного url можно так

```
<?php
//Берем данные из адресса
   $data = file_get_contents("https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=gastracker&action=gasoracle&apikey=YourApiKeyToken");
//Производим разбор полученного json
   $var=json_decode($data);
//Так можно добраться до данных
   echo "Выводим status-".$var->status."<br/>";
   echo "Выводим message-".$var->message."<br/>";
   echo "Выводим result->LastBlock-".$var->result->LastBlock;
?>
```

Comment: Андрей, спасибо

Comment: @Artem если ответ вам помог, отметьте его как принятый, галочка слева от ответа.